# Val in scala not immutable

Tags: scala

I am just playing with scala and did some very basic Val assignments, see below, if I reassign the val it seems be acting as if it were a var.

```
scala> val number = 17
number: Int = 17

scala> println(number)
17

scala> val number = 20
number: Int = 20

scala> number
res1: Int = 20

scala> val string = "ABC1234"
string: String = ABC1234

scala> println(string)
ABC1234

scala> val string = "DEF123"
string: String = DEF123

scala> println(string)
DEF123
```

I am not sure what I have done, I believe that I should get an error?

Thanks

Comment: Only in compiled code (or a script). In the REPL, it is as if every val is in its own namespace, and is hiding the previous val of the same name. No mutability, just invisibility.

Comment: you are re-defining the variable, again.

Comment: i doubt you are reassigning val, i think you are declaring them again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens only in the REPL, and only if you put the `val` keyword again.  It's a convenience feature so you can play in the REPL and keep reusing the same names.  Otherwise, you'd have to restart it, which would get annoying.

```
scala> val foo = "abc"
foo: String = abc

scala> foo = "def"
<console>:8: error: reassignment to val
       foo = "def"
       ^
```

However,

```
scala> val bar = 123
bar: Int = 123

scala> val bar = 456
bar: Int = 456
```

Neither of these is allowed by the compiler.

Also note that immutability is not a property of `val`s.  `val` in scala functions a lot like `final` in java -- you can only assign the value a single time.  The object, however could still be mutable.  For example:

```
scala> val foo = new Foo("abc", "def")
foo: Foo = Foo@6e905272

scala> foo.foo = "ghi"
foo.foo: String = ghi
```

Immutability is a property of the class.  "Changes" to the immutable object don't change the current instance, they create a new instance with the change made.  `String` and `List[T]` have this property.  The `Foo` class above does not.